# Add another controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I'm currently facing a problem of adding another controller and the problem is that

I have 2 controllers

```
class 1st_Controller extends CI_Controller {
}
```

and

```
class 2nd_Controller extends CI_Controller{
```

my 2 models are working perfectly fine and the only problem is that I need to call 1 model per each controller

for example
1st controller is for 1st model and 2nd controller is for 2nd model.

Now what I've tried so far is

```
class 2nd_Controller extends 1st_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('2nd_model','2ndmodel');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library("pagination");
        $this->load->library("session");
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'System Login';
        $get_all_inv = $this->2ndmodel->get_all();
        $data["tryvariable"] = $get_all_inv;
        $this->template->load('default_layout','contents','myview2nd', $data);
    }
}
```

I tried echo in my view like this

```
<?php echo $tryvariable; ?>
```

but no luck because the error says that it is an undefined variable .

Comment: You didn't load **template** in `__construct`, if you're trying to load some view, then that is wrong way. Using one model per each controller also should be done in another way. You should add in `__construct` the model you wanna use.

Comment: what do you mean I didn't load the temple

Comment: **$this->template->**, the program doesn't knows what is `template`

Comment: I do have a template.php on my libraries sir and it's working perfectly fine on the 1st_controller

Comment: Ok. If it's so, I think the problem is inside your `load` method in your hidden `template` library. Check it, during sending those variables with using of `print_r()` function. At least check if they're coming there

Comment: Perhaps it returns some string. If so, put it in variable and just make classic **$this->load->view('layout_page',['var'=>$var]);**

Comment: please don't forget: "Important. Class names must start with an uppercase letter." from docs: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#controllers

Comment: what is output of this statement `print_r($get_all_inv);`

Comment: I can't detect my second controller. But the 1st and 2nd model I can just call it right away on my constructor so its working fine

Comment: @AksenP they're not coming there sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did was write like this on my route to have my `2nd_Controller` working

```
$route['default_controller'] = '1st_Controller';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['2nd_Controller'] = '2nd_Controller';
```

Now everything is working perfectly. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Your second controller can't be define cause it's not define as `subclass_prefix` in your codeigniter application.

```
class 2nd_Controller extends 1st_Controller { //codeigniter don't recognize this.
}
```

The simpliest way to solve your problem is.. the fact that you can call multiple models in 1 Controller.

so you can have:

```
class 1st_Controller extends CI_Controller {
 public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('1st_model','1stmodel');
    $this->load->model('2nd_model','2ndmodel');
 }
}
```

or call just once.

```
class 2nd_Controller extends CI_Controller {
     public function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('2nd_model','2ndmodel');
     }
 }
```

Hope that helps.